# Enabling syntax highlighting for lisp in Docasaurus website

Tags: syntax-highlighting, docusaurus, prism-react-renderer

I'm trying to enable code block syntax highlighting for lisp on my Docusaurus website.  I added the following property on my `themeConfig`:

```
prism: {
  additionalLanguages: ['lisp'],
}
```

but it didn't seem to do anything.  It also seems that I cannot do any of the fancy code block stuff mentioned in the docs [here](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/code-blocks) including adding a `title=`

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: please provide a repro using new.docusaurus.io , it should work

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with one of my dependencies.  I literally copied over the dependencies list from new.docusaurus.io and ran `npm i` and then my code was highlighting away!